# Inconsistent UTF-8 encoding error HTML5

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a problem with my HTML5 webpage that I haven't been able to research an answer for. Im using swedish letters in the text (åäö) and started out by using UTF-8 encodig as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = 'sv'>

<head>
    <title> </title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name="description" content=' '>
    <link rel = 'stylesheet' href = './css/auroracss.css'>
</head>
```

This doesn't work for displaying the swedish letters in 3 out of 4 of my HTML5 pages, as I get the � chars when I preview. However, for the fourth page, using exactly the same head tag, the characters **are** displayed properly.

When I  switch out UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 the opposite is true - displaying the characters will work fine for 3 out of 4 pages but the same one which displayed properly with UTF-8 will show 
� chars when the ISO enconding is applied.

Everything validates.

I would like to stick to only one encoding choice here and not mix them even though that may be a quick fix. What is the cause for the problem?

Comment: This simply means the physical file is not encoded in the encoding that you specify in the header.

Answer (score 4):

The 3 out of 4 pages are, in fact, ISO-8859-1 encoded (or maybe windows-1252). Assuming that the server does not announce character encoding in HTTP headers (as it seems, since your `meta` tag takes effect), you simply need to a) declare `<meta charset=windows-1252>` for them instead of claiming them to be UTF-8 encoded, or b) convert them to UTF-8 encoded.

The conversion, which is generally preferable (UTF-8 is widely regarded as the way to go, even declared as the only allowed encoding in some “living standards”). You can use e.g. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/); using it, you simply open a file, use the program command to convert to UTF-8, and save the file.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I dont have enough rep to upvote your reply but it was of big help.

Comment: When an answer is correct, you can upvote it, but you have to indicate that it is correct by clicking the check mark on the left side of the answer